# How to add a marker from a different column to a seaborn pandas barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataset, code and plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10,15], ['matt', 13,10]]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Attempts','L4AverageAttempts']) 

f,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,figsize=(16,9))
sns.barplot(x='Attempts',y='Name',data=df3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can get a marker of some description (dot, *, shape, etc) to show that `tom`has averaged 15 (so is below his average) and  `matt` has averaged 10 so is above average. So a marker basxed off the `L4AverageAttempts` value for each person.

I have looked into `axvline` but that seems to be only a set number rather than a specific value for each y axis category. Any help would be much appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Use a scatter plot on the same axes?

Comment: thanks @DavidG ...any idea how that is done or references to look at? thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply plot a scatter plot on top of your bar plot using `L4AverageAttempts` as the x value:

You can use [seaborn.scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) for this. Make sure to set the `zorder` parameter so that the markers appear on top of the bars.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10,15], ['matt', 13,10]]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Attempts','L4AverageAttempts'])

f,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,figsize=(16,9))
sns.barplot(x='Attempts',y='Name',data=df3)

sns.scatterplot(x='L4AverageAttempts', y="Name", data=df3, zorder=10, color='k', edgecolor='k')

plt.show()
```

[image]